# Pythonic and efficient way of defining multiple regexes for use over many iterations

Tags: python, regex, performance

I am presently writing a Python script to process some 10,000 or so input documents. Based on the script's progress output I notice that the first 400+ documents get processed really fast and then the script slows down although the input documents all are approximately the same size.

I am assuming this may have to do with the fact that most of the document processing is done with regexes that I do not save as regex objects once they have been compiled. Instead, I recompile the regexes whenever I need them.

Since my script has about 10 different functions all of which use about 10 - 20 different regex patterns I am wondering what would be a more efficient way in Python to avoid re-compiling the regex patterns over and over again (in Perl I could simply include a modifier `//o`).

My assumption is that if I store the regex objects in the individual functions using

```
pattern = re.compile()
```

the resulting regex object will not be retained until the next invocation of the function for the next iteration (each function is called but once per document).

Creating a global list of pre-compiled regexes seems an unattractive option since I would need to store the list of regexes in a different location in my code than where they are actually used.

Any advice here on how to handle this neatly and efficiently?

Comment: No, it has to do with the fact that *your cache is depleted*.

Comment: are all functions applied to all documents?  because if so, @larsmans answer, while good, does not seem to explain the slowdown after 400 documents.  i would suggest profiling rather than guessing...

Comment: Have you checked how much memory you are using?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with profiling ... how does it work and what does it do for me?

Comment: Profiling: http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The re module caches compiled regex patterns. The cache is cleared when it reaches a size of re._MAXCACHE which by default is 100. (Since you have 10 functions with 10-20 regexes each (i.e. 100-200 regexes), your observed slow-down makes sense with the clearing of the cache.)

If you are okay with changing private variables, a quick and dirty fix to your program might be to set `re._MAXCACHE` to a higher value:

```
import re
re._MAXCACHE = 1000
```

Answer (score 5):

Last time I looked, re.compile maintained a rather small cache, and when it filled up, just emptied it. DIY with no limit:

```
class MyRECache(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = {}
    def compile(self, regex_string):
        if regex_string not in self.cache:
            self.cache[regex_string] = re.compile(regex_string)
        return self.cache[regex_string]
```

Comment: Or, even more succinctly, [derive from `dict` and overwrite `__missing__()`](https://gist.github.com/2230130).

Comment: @SvenMarnach: The code that I wrote can be understood by the person without the need to look up the `__voodoo__` docs.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how the cache is cleared when its capacity is used up ... are all entries flushed or just a few?

Comment: @Pat: If you don't believe that "emptied" means "flushed all entries", find `re.py` in your Python installation (mine is C:\Python27\Lib\re.py) and look for occurrences of `_cache` ... you should find `_cache = {}` and `_cache.clear()`

Answer (score 2):

Compiled regular expression are automatically cached by `re.compile`, `re.search` and `re.match`, but the maximum cache size is 100 in Python 2.7, so you're overflowing the cache.

> Creating a global list of pre-compiled regexes seems an unattractive option since I would need to store the list of regexes in a different location in my code than where they are actually used.

You can define them near the place where they are used: just before the functions that use them. If you reuse the same RE in a different place, then it would have been a good idea to define it globally anyway to avoid having to modify it in multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of "simple is better" I'd use a little helper function like this:

```
def rc(pattern, flags=0):
    key = pattern, flags
    if key not in rc.cache:
        rc.cache[key] = re.compile(pattern, flags)
    return rc.cache[key]

rc.cache = {}
```

Usage:

```
rc('[a-z]').sub...
rc('[a-z]').findall <- no compilation here
```

I also recommend you to try [regex](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex). Among many other advantages over the stock re, its MAXCACHE is 500 by default and won't get dropped completely on overflow.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who bothered to reply to my query. I will follow up on the many helpful pointers. Your support is much appreciated!.